# can we change class on iframe src page?

Tags: html, css

i am calling iframe on html page within it i have website url, i want to change logo position
i want add padding in it . so i copy same class from website css and apply on my html page with !important but it is not working.

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />


<style>
/*website class( just for example) 
    #header_logo {
        padding: 29px 0 18px 8px;
    }*/

    // my class

    #header_logo {
        padding: 29px 0 18px 50px!important;
    }


</style>
</head>

<body>
<iframe width="100%" height="600" allowtransparency="yes" frameborder="0" src="http://airtel.in">


</iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amit,

with javascript/jquery you change the the ID or the class (or add a class)..

for finding the contents in the iframe you could do somthing like:

$("iframe").contents().find('#selector')

Comment: have a look at: http://grasshopperpebbles.com/ajax/using-jquery-to-access-iframe-content, there's a more tutorial kind of page for solving the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably its a different domain - airtel.in? Then no, absolutely not, same-origin rules apply; http://developer.mozilla.org/En/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this is possible.

If you wish to change the styles of the page in the iframe you will need to change the styles on that actual page.

If this page is dynamic, and you have control over it, you could pass a querystring in the URL so that the class is only changed when viewed in an iframe. For example, change src to:

```
http://airtel.in?iframeview=1
```

Then depending on your programming language add:

```
if (Request.QueryString("iframeview")==1){
  //Make changes to add class here
}
```

Obviously this is dependant on whether you have control over the page displayed in the iframe however.